# Continuous time Ruelle-Perron-Frobenius

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $L$ be a $n \times n$ $Q$-matrix, $p_0$ probability vector such that $L(p_0) = p_0$. Then, by countinuous time Markov Chain Theory, we get thar $\mathcal{P}^t= e^{tL}$ is stochastic. Let $V\colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $V$ is constant in cylinders of the form $\{X_0 = c\}$. Then there are:

a) a unique positive function $u_V \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ constant equal to the value $u_V^i$ in each cylinder $\{X_0 = i\}$, $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$;\

b) a unique probability vector $\mu_V \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such tha $\mu_V({i}) > 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n (u_V)_i (\mu_V)_i = 1$.

c) a real positive valeu $\lambda_V$ such that for any $s > 0$
        $$e^{-s\lambda_V} u_V e^{s(L+V)} = u_V;$$

Moreover, given $s>0$, $e^{-s \lambda_V}e^{s(L+V)}\mu_V = \mu_V.$

Can someone give me a reference where I should find this result? Or maybe some proof.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the idea of the statement is? It sounds like you're asking for the continuous time version of the usual irreducible+aperiodic+finite state space <-> ergodic result, but the notation is so awkward that it's hard to tell. As for that, you can very nearly get the result by simply considering a subsampled discrete time chain with transition probability matrix $e^{hL}$ and showing that it's irreducible and aperiodic. Then you get the result along any sequence of times $hn$, and the only issue is ensuring that all such sequences give the same limit.

Comment: Actually, the theorem is asking a little bit more, because there is no need for aperiodicity...

Comment: I understand, but that's because in continuous time, the analogue of aperiodicity is automatic. So it still seems like it's analogous.

Comment: Even with this perturbation $V$?

Comment: That's what I was asking for elaboration on. Qualitatively speaking, how is your question different from "please give a reference on the continuous time version of the ergodic theorem for DTMCs?" Is it because $L$ is perturbed so that $L+V$ is no longer a generator matrix?

Comment: Yes, exactly! L +V is no longer a generator matrix, but we can assume, without loss of generality that V is positive. 

And I will also accept the reference oF continuous time verstion of the ergodic theorem ofor DTMCs :)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72295/discussion-between-luisa-borsato-and-ian).